# Save structure of an object

Tags: r

Is there a possibility to seriallize the structure of an object in R. By seriallization I mean something similar to `utils::str()` or `base::structure()` function. That functions work very good, but they just print the structure without an option to assign it to a variable.

I tried to do that using a recursion (just to get classes):

```
x <- list("aaa",
          c("asd", "test", "asdfre"),
          b = list("bbbb"),
          c1 = as.list(c("l1", "l2")),
          c = list("aaa", 
                   b = "bbbbb", 
                   list("aaa", 
                        s = c(123, 122)), 
                   l = list(a = list("aa", 
                                     "bb"), 
                            b = c(12, 123))))




getStructure <- function(x){
  if(!is.list(x)){
    return(list(class(x)))
  } else{
      sapply(x, function(x) { if(!is.null(x)) getStructure(x) })
  }
}

getStructure(x)
```

But it's not working in a similar way like `str()` and `structure()` functions work.

Comment: Can you expand on why you are doing this? For example, if you _could_ assign the output of `utils::str()` to a variable, what would you do with it afterwards?

Comment: Are you looking for `capture.output`? Something like `x = capture.output(str(mtcars))`?

Comment: @joran
I'm developing a ML tool, which gives me a specific output in R and then it's used by some other code to provide visualizations. If I'm going to expand that tool or patch some bugs then I have to test the new output structure with the previous one. So that would give me a tool to check the integrity with my previous output.

Comment: My best guess is you simply want to use `save`, `load` and then compare objects with `all.equal`.

Comment: @Gregor That worked very good and was fast. If you post that as an answer I'll mark it as solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`capture.output` is the general way to, well, capture anything that's normally printed to the console.

```
x = capture.output(str(mtcars))
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to accomplish?  Do you need to send the data in some kind of text format?  If not--if you just need to save the object to disk so that it can be loaded into R later--then you can use `save`:

```
foo <- list(x=c(1, 2, 3), y=c("a", "b", "c"))
save(foo, file="foo.rdata")
```

Now exit R and restart it.

```
load("foo.rdata")
foo
; $x
; [1] 1 2 3
;
; $y
; [1] "a" "b" "c"
```

Comment: I want to check only the structure (classes, variable names, length), not the whole object with data.